# Is there a way to get from a polynomial to a link with the polynomial as its Jones polynomial?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Sorry for the convoluted wording of my question.

Suppose that I have some polynomial $P$.  Is there an algorithm for getting  a link $L$ such that $V(L)=P$?  Is there an algorithm for getting the projection of this link easily?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't remember hearing of one... Maybe a heuristic reason why is that such an algorithm applied to $P=1$ would probably give a family of knots with Jones polynomial $1$, but the conjecture that there is only one such knot (the unknot) complicates things.  (This question was asked on MathOverflow https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320154/set-of-jones-polynomials-as-the-knot-varies last year.)